# Unable to put the floating div tags on their required places

Tags: css, html

I have 5 `<div>` tags on my page.

1. container `<div>`
2. header `<div>`
3. left panel `<div>`
4. middle panel `<div>`
5. right panel `<div>`

The left panel, middle panel and the right panel `<div>` are placed side by side using `CSS float left`. Now the problem comes when the fetched data is displayed in the middle panel `<div>` and its height starts increasing according to the amount of fetched data. Left panel `<div>` stays where it suppose to be but the right panel `<div>` changes its margin as shown in the figure.

[image]

This image explains the exact situation. Below is my CSS.

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

.header{
   height:100px;
   width:100%; 
}

.left_panel{
    width:130px;
    float:left;
}


.middle_panel{
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}

.right_panel{
    float:right;
    width:130px;
}
```

Please help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: A picture is worth 1k words but a fiddle is worth 100k words. Can you post one showing this behavior?

Comment: Heck, I'd settle for your HTML.

Comment: But who knows what crazy content he has in the right column? Perhaps it has a paragraph with a giant top margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is being caused because the combined width of your left, middle and right panels are exceeding the width of your page.

Try something like my fiddle where I have set the width of the left and right panels to 15% so under no circumstance will they exceed 100%

```
.left_panel {
  width:15%;
  float:left;
  background: yellow;
}

.middle_panel {
  width:70%;
  float:left;
  background: blue; 
}

.right_panel {
  float:right;
  width:15%;
  background: pink;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPgt9/

Comment: I want to point out that if this was the case, the right column would actually be entirely below the middle column, not halfway down. http://jsfiddle.net/WPgt9/1/

Comment: I don't think he said it aligns perfectly with the middle column, the picture may not reflect the entire truth and it may be coming below the middle panel.

Comment: Actually the picture is showing the exact behaviour of my problem. Actually the middle panel does not contains the paragraph tags but only div tags and links. Everything looks fine if there is no data fetched. But it all mess up as soon as the data is displayed in the middle div.

Comment: Please post your HTML code after the data has been loaded in a JS fiddle and post the link below.

Comment: I have posted my HTML on fiddle. Here is the link of my code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtKUP/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="left_panel">Left</div>
    <div class="middle_panel">
       Middle
           </div>
    <div class="right_panel">Right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

.container{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;

}

.header{
   height:100px;
   width:100%; 
    background-color:green;
}

.left_panel{
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    height:400px;
}


.middle_panel{
    width:70%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    height:500px;
}

.right_panel{
    float:right;
    width:15%;
    background-color:red;
    height:400px;
}
```

**Fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/WPgt9/9/

Comment: Cannot see the right panel being bottom aligned with the middle panel. Even after I changed the width to 130px and here is the output as seen in an image. http://i.imgur.com/IWTMs6U.png

Comment: he said right panel should not change its margin right? then it is correct. did he say it should be bottom aligned buddy?? if you want output similar to the image refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WPgt9/14/

Comment: Actually, the widths of both right and left panels should be in pixels and the middle panel's width should be in percentage. As soon as the middle panel is populated, its size increases and there should not be any effect on the neighbourhood panels (left panel and right panel). @Rahul Kadukar helped me out and now everything works fine.